# Label does not adjust Font Size to fit width

Tags: swift, label, uilabel, size, font-size

[image]

This is how my app looks although I entered this code inside my ViewController class:

```
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label.text = "Hello World"
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
}
```

Comment: can u be more precise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text data is not more than `label` width that's why label `text` `font` is same as already set.
IF your text data is more then label `width` then it will `adjust font` according to the `width`.

> Please check with label text: **"This is the demo to test label text is adjustable or not. You need to test it with this demo data"**

Your label `font` will adjust according to the width.

Comment: so how to solve another issue? to actually fit text within its container, and not only if it's bigger but also if it's smaller than its container size

Answer (score 0):

The font will adjust if the given text is greater than the width of the label.

Try this in playground:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
 override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)

    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.backgroundColor =  UIColor.lightGray

    label.text = "Hello World! How are you doing today? "
    label.textColor = .black

    view.addSubview(label)
    self.view = view
 }
}
 // Present the view controller in the Live View window
 PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

The result is the following:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my UILabel font to dynamically adjust to the necessary size to fit into its parent by following this simple [gitconnected](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/create-a-uilabel-with-dynamic-font-size-in-swift-5-f49ccc26dc5f) article **(See link to get all required code!!)**. I only needed to make two adjustments which were adding the lines `label.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters` and `label.numberOfLines = 1` so that my label creation now looked like this...

```
let dynamicFontLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 40)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.numberOfLines = 1;
    label.textColor = .black
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
```

The `label.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters` property ensured that if my font size was too large and needed to be downsized, my text would still remain centered vertically in the UILabel. I also only wanted my text to only span one line so if you want more than that you can just remove the `label.numberOfLines = 1` property.